# SQL query for a user input match using python connection

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
def showPatient():

    patient_lname = input("\nEnter the last name of the patient "
                    "you would like to search for: \n")

    query = c.execute("SELECT CONCAT(fname, " ", mi, " ", lname) "
                  "FROM Patients WHERE lname LIKE ?)", (patient_lname,))
```

Prompts with an error message in showPatient

"FROM Patients WHERE lname LIKE ?)", (patient_lname,))

sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

```
    resultset = c.fetchall()

    if not resultset:
        print("Sorry, the last name you entered does not match any patients "
              "in the hospital.") #if there are no results this is printed
    else:
        for result in resultset:
            result = ' '.join(result)
            print("\n\t", result)
```

Comment: Why do you have an unbalanced `)` immediately after `?`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python strings delimited with `"`. In this particular `execute()` call, you have four of them; the resulting SQL statement looks like this:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(fname, , mi, , lname)
FROM Patients WHERE lname LIKE ?)
```

In SQL, you should delimit strings with `'`. (And the standard SQL way of concatenating strings is the [`||` operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#binaryops), and you have a superfluous `)`.)